# Hide on hover jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using javascript to show/hide text inside a div on hover.

There are 4 div blocks with the same class - `.main_content`

Each block has a link and text. The text is hidden by default.

When the cursor is on `.main_content`, only the text of this block should appear. Why does the `hover` function not toggle the text?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function hover() {
    var IndexItem = getElementsByClassName("main_content");
    if (IndexItem.hover()) {
      index = IndexItem.index();
      IndexItem: eq(index).toggle();

    };
  };;
})
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "SevillaDecor";
  /* Гарнитура шрифта */
  src: url(/SevillaDecor.ttf);
  /* Путь к файлу со шрифтом */
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: "SevillaDecor", Regular;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  font-weight: 600;
  /* font-style: oblique; */
}

a {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #0af5ec;
}

.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  /* top: 0px; */
  /* left: 0px; */
  /* clear: both; */
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  /* overflow: hidden; */
}

.text {
  /* display: block; */
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.main_content {
  font-size: 30pt;
  /* position: relative; */
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  /* margin: 0; */
  /* padding: 0; */
  overflow: hidden;
  /* background-size: cover; */
  /* text-align: center !important; */
}

.main_content img {
  /* position:absolute; */
  /* min-width: 50%; */
  /* max-width: 100%; */
  /* background-size: cover; */
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.block_center {
  /* display:none; */
  position: absolute;
  width: 185pt;
  height: 185pt;
  /* font-size: 15pt; */
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -95pt;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* background-size: contain; */
  /* text-align: center !important; */
}

.block_center img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.block_center p {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-top: 5%;
  margin-bottom: 4%;
}


/*
.main_content::after {
 content: ".";
 display: block;
 height: 0;
 clear: both;
}

.main::after{
 content: ".";
 display: block;
 height: 0;
 clear: both;
}
*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="main_content">
    <a href "#" class="back_image">
      <img src="Images/1.jpeg" />
      <div class="text">
        <p> О нас </p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="main_content">
    <a href="#" class="back_image">
      <img src="Images/2.jpeg" />
      <div class="text">
        <p> Top </p>
      </div>

    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="main_content">
    <a href="#" class="back_image">
      <img src="Images/3.jpeg" />
      <div class="text">
        <p> New </p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="main_content">
    <a href="#" class="back_image">
      <img src="Images/4.jpeg" />
      <div class="text">
        <p> Исполнители </p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="block_center">
    <a href="# " class="center_image ">
      <img src="Images/vinyl.gif " />
      <div class="text ">
        <p> <a href="# "> Личный кабинет </a> </p>
        <p> <a href="# "> Гарантии </a> </p>
        <p> <a href="# "> Оплата\Доставка </a> </p>
        <p> <a href="# "> Контакты </a> </p>
      </div>
      <!-- </a> -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: so what is your question?

Comment: Why you need JS for this? Why not `.main_content:hover .text {display: block;}`?

Comment: I want blocks with text to appear when hovering over the cursor

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` is an HTML collection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually super simple.

There are two quick ways to do this. The easiest way is with the CSS `:hover` pseudo selector like this:

```
.text {
    display:none;
}
.main_content:hover .text {
    display: block;
}
```

Or with JavaScript by using the `find()` statement on your `$(this)` selector like this:

```
$('.main-content').mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).find('.text').fadeIn();
});

$('.main-content').mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).find('.text').fadeOut();
})
```

Comment: @VladislavNovikov wonderful - I am glad I could help! Please don't forget to upvote and mark as accepted answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Pure CSS surely:

```
.main_content > a > .text {
    display: none;
}

.main_content:hover > a > .text {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Much better! Thanks - My OCD can rest now ;)

Comment: It was a question that was gonna be plagued with answers, i had to be quick, unfortunately too quick. A problem I am oh to familar with ;)

Comment: Hahahaha I know the feeling too ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.main_content').mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).find('.text').css('display','block');
    });
    $('.main_content').mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).find('.text').css('display','none');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with the solution https://jsfiddle.net/5ove7e46/

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('.main_content').hover(function(){
    $(this).find('div.text').toggle();
   });  
});
```

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: "SevillaDecor"; /* Гарнитура шрифта */
    src: url(/SevillaDecor.ttf); /* Путь к файлу со шрифтом */
   }

* {
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}
body {
 font-family: "SevillaDecor", Regular;
 font-variant: small-caps;
 font-weight: 600;
 /* font-style: oblique; */
}

a {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #0af5ec;
}

.wrapper {
    position: absolute;

    /* top: 0px; */
    /* left: 0px; */
    /* clear: both; */
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    /* overflow: hidden; */
}


.text {
    /* display: block; */
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
   top:0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.main_content {
    font-size: 30pt;
    /* position: relative; */
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    /* margin: 0; */
    /* padding: 0; */
    overflow: hidden;
    /* background-size: cover; */
    /* text-align: center !important; */
}

.main_content img{
    /* position:absolute; */
 /* min-width: 50%; */
    /* max-width: 100%; */
    /* background-size: cover; */
    width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}

.block_center {
 /* display:none; */
    position: absolute;
    width: 185pt;
    height: 185pt;
    /* font-size: 15pt; */
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -95pt;
    overflow: hidden;
    /* background-size: contain; */
    /* text-align: center !important; */
}

.block_center img {
 width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.block_center p {
 display: block;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-top: 5%;
    margin-bottom: 4%;
}





/*
.main_content::after {
 content: ".";
 display: block;
 height: 0;
 clear: both;
}

.main::after{
 content: ".";
 display: block;
 height: 0;
 clear: both;
}
*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class = "wrapper">
  <div class = "main_content"  > 
      <a href="#" class = "back_image" >
          <img src = "Images/1.jpeg"/>
          <div class="text">
              <p> О нас </p>
          </div>
      </a>
  </div>

  <div class = "main_content" >
      <a href = "#" class = "back_image">
          <img src = "Images/2.jpeg"/>
          <div class = "text">
              <p> Top </p>
          </div>

      </a>
  </div>
```

**Code changes**

**CSS**

```
.text{display: none;}
```

**JS**

```
$('.main_content').hover(function(){
    $(this).find('div.text').toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$( ".main_content" ).hover(
  function() {
    $(this).show();
  }, function() {
    $(this).hide();
  }
);
```

Comment: Perhaps provide a more complete answer? Instead of commenting `//do something on hover` - perhaps show how he would need to hide/display the text. That would make this a much more helpful answer :)

Answer (score 0):

This effect can be achieved in CSS:

```
.main_content img {
  opacity:1;
}
.main_content .text {
  opacity:0;
}
.main_content .text,
.main_content img {
  transition:opacity 0.6s linear;
}
.main_content:hover img {
  opacity: 0;
}
.main_content:hover .text {
  opacity: 1;
 }
```

When you hover on the container, the img fades out and the text fades in, so that

> only the text of this block should appear

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "SevillaDecor";
  /* Гарнитура шрифта */
  src: url(/SevillaDecor.ttf);
  /* Путь к файлу со шрифтом */
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: "SevillaDecor", Regular;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  font-weight: 600;
  /* font-style: oblique; */
}

a {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #0af5ec;
}

.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  /* top: 0px; */
  /* left: 0px; */
  /* clear: both; */
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  /* overflow: hidden; */
}

.text {
  /* display: block; */
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.main_content {
  font-size: 30pt;
  /* position: relative; */
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  /* margin: 0; */
  /* padding: 0; */
  overflow: hidden;
  /* background-size: cover; */
  /* text-align: center !important; */
}

.main_content img {
  /* position:absolute; */
  /* min-width: 50%; */
  /* max-width: 100%; */
  /* background-size: cover; */
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.block_center {
  /* display:none; */
  position: absolute;
  width: 185pt;
  height: 185pt;
  /* font-size: 15pt; */
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -95pt;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* background-size: contain; */
  /* text-align: center !important; */
}

.block_center img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.block_center p {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-top: 5%;
  margin-bottom: 4%;
}


.main_content img {
  opacity:1;
}
.main_content .text {
  opacity:0;
}
.main_content .text,
.main_content img {
  transition:opacity 0.6s linear;
}
.main_content:hover img {
  opacity: 0;
}
.main_content:hover .text {
  opacity: 1;
 }
/*
.main_content::after {
 content: ".";
 display: block;
 height: 0;
 clear: both;
}

.main::after{
 content: ".";
 display: block;
 height: 0;
 clear: both;
}
*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="main_content">
    <a href "#" class="back_image">
      <img src="Images/1.jpeg" />
      <div class="text">
        <p> О нас </p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="main_content">
    <a href="#" class="back_image">
      <img src="Images/2.jpeg" />
      <div class="text">
        <p> Top </p>
      </div>

    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="main_content">
    <a href="#" class="back_image">
      <img src="Images/3.jpeg" />
      <div class="text">
        <p> New </p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="main_content">
    <a href="#" class="back_image">
      <img src="Images/4.jpeg" />
      <div class="text">
        <p> Исполнители </p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="block_center">
    <a href="#" class="center_image">
      <img src="Images/vinyl.gif " />
      <div class="text ">
        <p> <a href="# "> Личный кабинет </a> </p>
        <p> <a href="# "> Гарантии </a> </p>
        <p> <a href="# "> Оплата\Доставка </a> </p>
        <p> <a href="# "> Контакты </a> </p>
      </div>
      <!-- </a> -->
  </div>
</div>
```